# ArcGIS tool to batch re-order directions of polylines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, arcgis-10.6

I'm working with multiple datasets that each have thousands of polylines in their respective shapefiles. Is there an ArcGIS tool that allows me to batch re-order the directions of the lines? For example, order all lines N to S, then W to E. Will ultimately do this in ArcPy, so I don't want to use editor.

Example screenshot below. The lines were digitized in different directions (sometimes "top-down" and sometimes "bottom-up"). I just want to set a uniform rule.
[image]

Comment: Add geometry attributes - start,mid, end. Select lines by attributes starty>endy. Use flip edit tool.

Comment: someone downvoted this but i think this is legit question. I was looking for the same functionality. I didn't find anything easy to use so i built my self a tool with ArcObjects - won't help you much so I am only commenting here. My tool can flip the direction of all selected lines or flip then into any compass direction. find it useful when correcting flows of watercourses or geological faults, etc.

Comment: thanks @JakubSisakGeoGraphics for the comments--I'm actually doing this for faults...would be interested about what you have done (even if it's just written description and not code)!